# Grub2 don't see my second HDD

Tags: boot, grub2, grub, boot-loader

When the new distro is installed it makes grub2 boot menu, but it does not consider my second HDD where I have Windows7. So I tried to edit grubs cfg file but with no success. Also tried to insert this partition with Grub's Customizer 'add' option, but it trows errors again.

But when I booted system with Supergrubdisk and start to browse everything it shows me all OS-es on both disks and I can start any of them. I tried to copy this menuscript to grub.cfg but, again, it fails to boot windows7.

My question: where to find the script which will browse all OS-es like supergrubdisk do, using installed grub2 CLI?

Comment: what is cfg file generated by grub2-mkconfig -o file.cfg?

Comment: Output is the same as grub.cfg; dough got to use grub-mkconfig if it matters. 'grub-install -v' trows 'grub-install.real (GRUB) 2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1'.

Comment: what says os-prober?

Comment: It found only first HDD.

Comment: Ok, because no enough info can you see if this can help you: [https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/64784/os-prober-doesnt-seem-to-find-windows-7/](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/64784/os-prober-doesnt-seem-to-find-windows-7/)

Comment: Thank you, but please take look again what was my question.